# Black Rectangle instead of texture

Tags: xna, c#, monogame

I am trying to draw a textured ractangle like in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb464051.aspx) example. But instead of a texture the rectangle is just black.

Draw method:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

    effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
    effect.World = world;
    effect.Projection = camera.Projection;
    effect.View = camera.View;
    effect.TextureEnabled = true;
    effect.Texture = grass;
    effect.LightingEnabled = true;

    foreach (var pass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
    {
        pass.Apply();

        GraphicsDevice.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, quad[0].Vertices, 0, 4, AlignedQuad.Indexes, 0, 2);
    }

    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

The `effect` is like a in the example a `BasicEffect`. The texture is existing and is  not a black rectangle.

What am I missing or doing wrong? Thank you for your help.

Comment: The problem is in the code that you don't show. The code you show [works](http://i.gyazo.com/3b23a499d22043e31a1513158ab5067a.png) for me. Just use the code from the example. There is no point in messing with the `effect` and changing it in every single draw call. In the example that code was in `LoadContent()` so that it only gets called once.

Comment: Copied everything into a new project but I am still getting a black rectangle

Comment: @Shiro could you upload your code i want to test if your program is generating a black rectangle too.

Comment: You are saying that you get a black rectangle with the code of the example you posted ? [Textured_Quad_Sample.zip](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=198916) is the download link from the link you posted. That's what I downloaded as well.

Comment: Disable lighting and try again. If works, you know where is the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `effect.Alpha = 1f;` 
The alpha channel was probably premultiplied (check the texture properties in your content section).